# How to select start from partial text ,end with value range SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, between

I have a list of text contain value in the column call "Name"

```
Name
J001500
J001510
J001520
J001600
J001610
J001620
J001700
J001710
J001720
J001800
J001810
J001820
```

Want to select from range of **start form J0016xx to J0017xx** ,
how can i achieve this ? except the method below :

```
WHERE Name BETWEEN 'J0016%' AND 'J0017%'
ORDER by Name
```

Both normal SQL and Regex way are welcome.

Comment: Base on some limitations of my environment , i cannot use ORDER by in my PC

Comment: ORDER BY is there only to sort your results, not to condition. Filtering values is based on WHERE clause in your case. Which DBMS are you using? Answer may be product specific

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Many thanks and Apologize clearly for the background informations as i am new for SQL . My DBMS is Oracle .

Comment: Edited my answer to include regex solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is:

```
WHERE Name >= 'J0016' AND Name < 'J0018'
```

Why is this "best"?  First, it returns the right values and is not misleading.  Using `BETWEEN` is misleading, because `'J0018'` would be included in the results (although not if there are any other characters).

Second, the optimizer can take advantage of an index (if available) for the query.

Comment: Thankyou Gordon Linoff , its simple , precise , surprisingly works for any situations. Great explanations of the misleading of using BETWEEN as its really misleading in this situation.Inspiring answer as i thought regex is the only solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
with test as (select 'J001500' as name from dual union
              select 'J001510' from dual union
              select 'J001520' from dual union
              select 'J001600' from dual union
              select 'J001610' from dual union
              select 'J001620' from dual union
              select 'J001700'   from dual union
              select 'J001710' from dual union
              select 'J001720'  from dual union
              select 'J001800' from dual union
              select 'J001810'  from dual union
              select 'J001820'   from dual)
--select * from test where name >= 'J0017' and name < 'J0018'
select * from test where name between 'J0017' and 'J0018'
```

Comment: Thnakyou hotfix

Answer (score 2):

**(1)** Based on `LIKE` operator and `_` which stands for exactly one character:

```
WHERE Name LIKE 'J0016__' OR Name LIKE 'J0017__'
```

**(2)** Based on alphanumerical sorting of string this will also work, but doesn't ensure there are two more characters following after specified text:

```
WHERE Name BETWEEN 'J0016' AND 'J0018' -- note 18 here which means < 'J0018'
```

**(3)** Using `REGEXP_LIKE` Oracle function with case sensitive search:

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(Name, '^J001[67].{2}$','c')
```

Explanation:

- `^J001` - starts with J001
- `[67]` - has 6 or 7 as next character
- `.{2}$` - ends with exactly two characters

---

I'd personally go with either (1) or (3) just because it is more bullet-proof whenever you would need to modify conditions (eg numbers in strings, because (2) could break and would need you to change argument places). In case you're thinking of portability then `LIKE` from (1) is a better choice, since (3) is product specific.

Comment: Thankyou Kamil G .My database engine is Oracle .I believe REGEX may be my only solution . Because the actual dataset have to be selected out with a range more than two START FROM pattern , e.g. J00816xx , J00817xx .  J00818xx . Or i have to adding more codes corresponding the patterns of START FROM i need like :   WHERE Name LIKE 'J0016__' OR Name LIKE 'J0017__' OR Name LIKE 'J0018__' OR Name LIKE 'J0019__' ........

Comment: @rane pick whichever you find more convenient for you. Just keep in mind that there is no correlation between how much you type in SQL vs how fast it executes :)

Comment: Thankyou Kami.G , Make use of regex combination  is the most flexible to many situation and speed

Answer (score 1):

Logic: Extract 4th and 5th character in string and if it is in between 16 and 17 then give it as output.

I don't know which RDMS you are using. I can modify it as per your RDBMS. Below query will work in SQL Server

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(name,4,2)) BETWEEN '16' AND '17'
ORDER by Name
```

Comment: Thankyou Luv . Its a nice way other than all methods i assumed .